# Mkdirs failed to create file

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mkdir

Give me some help...

I just operating some examples right now.
in data-algorithms-book by Partisan

I uploaded my text file on HDFS and made a run.sh file already but when i just run on my spark , It makes erorr like this
:

> Mkdirs failed to create file:/output/2/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201603120204_0000_m_000000_3 (exists=false, cwd=file:/home/hadoop/spark-1.6.0/work/app-20160312020423-0001/0)

and this gets me crazy... please give me some solution ...

Comment: Maybe you don't have permissions, have you checked that?

Comment: Please provide few details: what cluster? How do you submit job? How do you write file? I think your problem is in specifying path of your output: you see that temp file is written locally(file://) instead of writing it to hdfs